# Optimization: Declaring variables used for a class constructor outside of loop?

Tags: java

I was monitoring my application with the task manager and saw that the RAM usage is constantly going up.

I quickly noticed that I initialized a new variable in every iteration of the for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < List.size(); i++)
{

    data = List.get(i); //This is already declared outside
    CustomThread thread2= new CustomThread(data);
    executor.execute(thread2);

}
```

Now, does declaring `CustomThread thread2` outside of the loop be of any benefit?

Would the `execute(thread2)` be still connected to the original object when accessing it later? Or maybe, the object is overwritten, and gets overwritten for every `execute`, causing it to do the same exact thing (the behaviour is based on the data) ?

EDIT:

I roughly need 200 threads (they are not too heavy but they do connect to a website), also, the snippet and the code before it, is a `runnable` that gets called every 20 seconds (so yeah, I'd create roughly 600 threads per minute)

Comment: Attach a profiler to the program to find out where the memory is being allocated.  In general, yes - declaring a variable outside of a loop that is an instance of a 'heavy' object is better than doing it in the loop.  But you don't really know what the actual bottleneck in your program is, you are just guessing.

Comment: I will surely do that. I just wanted to know if this is valid and works as I expect it to work.

Comment: @AmirAfghani: Just *declaring* the variable outside won't help. If you reduce actual allocations, that's good, but there's no evidence of that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you *declare the variable* doesn't matter except for scoping; where you *create the object* matters, because presumably you need to call `executor.execute` with *different* `CustomThread` objects on each call. (If you don't, then yes, obviously, create a single object outside the loop and reuse it.)

The way you have it is how I'd write it, except:

1. You might just do away with the variable entirely if you don't need it for anything else:

   ```
   executor.execute(new CustomThread(data));
   ```
2. I might declare `data` within the loop body unless you have a good reason for declaring it outside.

...since there's no benefit to broadening the scope of that `thread2` variable if you don't need it outside the loop.

Comment: Wouldn't broadening the scope be better in this case? I mean, instead of making a new object for every iteration, declaring it outside (so making the objects just once) should be more efficient, right?

Comment: @J.Nato: Again: Moving the declaration of the variable doesn't change anything from a memory allocation standpoint (except that the last object you assign to the variable will be held a bit longer than it is with the declaration where it is). If you need a new `CustomThread` object for each call to `executor.execute` (and I presume you do), then where you have the declaration is correct.

Answer (score 0):

No.
When you use the keyword **new** you create a new memory address, so you will be always creating a new thread for each iteration.

Comment: I'd make about 600 threads per minute (see edit), isn't there a way to make this more efficient?

Comment: but you need to pass data to the constructor of the thread, so you need to call the new keyword

Comment: @J.Nato: Sounds like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to create 600 threads? As opposed to just creating 600 *runnables*? And do you really need 600? What are you using the executor to do? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is rather clear that the actual code doesn't cause **directly** the memory consumption issue.

`data` is an element of the `List`. Assigning it a temporary variable doesn't create a new object. It just creates a "link" to the actual object.

Your problem is probably related to what you perform in your threads.
Creating and running hundreds of threads concurrently that create objects may finally created a number very important of objects.
Rather than guessing, use a monitoring tool as JVisualVM and you should easily find the culprit.